# Using page text to select `html` element using`Beautiful Soup`

Tags: python, html, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I have a page which contains several repetitions of: `<div...><h4>...<p>...` For example:

```
html = '''
<div class="proletariat">
<h4>sickle</h4>
<p>Ignore this text</p>
</div>
<div class="proletariat">
<h4>hammer</h4>
<p>This is the text we want</p>
</div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

If I write `print soup.select('div[class^="proletariat"] > h4 ~ p')`, I get:

```
[<p>Ignore this text</p>, <p>This is the text we want</p>]
```

How do I specify that I only want the text of p when it is preceded by `<h4>hammer</h4>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = '''
<div class="proletariat">
<h4>sickle</h4>
<p>Ignore this text</p>
</div>
<div class="proletariat">
<h4>hammer</h4>
<p>This is the text we want</p>
</div>
'''
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.find("h4", text=re.compile('hammer')).next_sibling.next.text)
This is the text we want
```

Comment: no worries, you're welcome,  you will have to tweak it a bit but the `next_sibling` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`:contains()` could help here, but it is not supported.

Taking this into account, you can use `select()` in conjunction with the [`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
print next(h4.find_next_sibling('p').text 
           for h4 in soup.select('div[class^="proletariat"] > h4') 
           if h4.text == "hammer")
```